Flow -> Screen -> 3 number fields where the last one auto-calculates after any 2 are filled in?
I'm brand new to both Salesforce AND to this community, so please forgive me if I've missed something horrendously obvious!
What I'm trying to do:
With my very new/loose grasp on what Flows and Screen Components are, I'm trying to add 3 number components to a screen. I want the user to enter amounts for any 2 of these fields, and regardless of which 2 they choose, the 3rd will auto-calculate. It's like a triangle - no matter what, the 3 fields have to reconcile with each other.
A concrete example: A * B = C
Three fields - items, cost per item, and total cost.

Items are the number of items
Cost Per Item is a fixed amount per item
Total Cost is a product of (Items x Cost Per Item)

But with basic math, any 1 of the 3 can be inferred if you have the other two.
What I've tried:
With each field, taking the Default Value -> New Resource -> Formula, and trying to calculate based off the other two fields from there. For each field, I AM able to reference the values of the other two in the formula, and the formula saves without issue.
What ends up happening, though, is I'm stuck in this circular logic where when I run the screen to test it, I get "infinity" in one or more of the fields after typing in them.
I suspect this might be a situation where the system can't do what I want it to do, and I'm trying to bite off more than I should be as a beginner for now.  :/
Any advice? Thank you!

Not an answer per se, but whenever I come across a design such as this I'll always look to other software to see how they solve it.  If no one else does it, it's probably not a good idea, either from a usability point of view or just not being technically possible.  If you were to do this in Excel, how would you do it? It would be a mix of a formula to calculate the total, and using the Goal Seek feature.

Your approach is what I would do too. But yes as you've noted, you can't avoid the infinity issue because every time you enter one value, two of the others are calculated based on a value that momentarily doesn't exist.
My recommendation to get around this would be to let the user choose which field they want to auto calculate via a picklist or radio buttons. Then based on their selection, the auto calculated field will be the only one with a default value, and will be disabled for input. This prevents you from getting the infinity error but does require input on the other two fields (which is what you said you intended)
To make this work, you would need to:

Modify your default values for each box to something like: IF( {!Automatically_calculate_the} <> {!Price_per_Item_Choice}, null , {!Total_Cost}/{!No_of_Items} )
Disable the auto calculated field based on the selection for the picklist or radio buttons. You can create a boolean formula for each box that evaluates to true if the picklist or radio buttons have that field selected. Something like {!Automatically_calculate_the}={!Total_Cost_Choice}

Once done, it can look something like this:



I really like this approach! Thank you very much!

Maybe you should have separate resources for input and separate formulas for all 3 of them to calculate and display them on screen based on conditions (if populated show what is populated, if not, calculate).
Something like this:



Thank you for this idea! It's not quite what I was looking for, but it does spark additional ideas I can try. Appreciate you taking the time!  :)
